# Git push to a new repository on remote, initializing on the fly

Tags: linux, ssh, git

Basically I'd like to set up a repository on a remote server on the fly. Usually a repository has to be initialized on the remote with `init --bare` before one can push commits from another device. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Ideally I have two points I'd like to fulfill:

1. Leave the client side unchanged, meaning no setup other than `git remote add ...`.
2. Use SSH as the transfer protocol.

What I've thought of so far:

1. Ignoring the SSH demand. By pushing over HTTPS instead I could host a HTTPS server that initializes non-existing repositories before accepting the push.
2. Changing git functionality on the server side, hijacking push commands (called in the git-shell?). I have found no documentation on what takes place on the server side when pushing over SSH so I've not been able to further investigate this possible solution.
3. Related to #2, I could implement a SSH server running on the remote, initializing non-existing repositories before running further commands. But as with #2, I've found no documentation on the push pipeline.

Clarification:

Can I push to a remote that has not yet initialized the repository?
Can I sufficiently detect incoming pushes, initializing the repository before continuing?

Comment: Why `svn` flag?

Comment: Maybe you could use a configuration mangement like `ansible` to set up the remote repo. It's agentless, so all you need is SSH access to the machine. You could run a playbook on the remote machine to set up the repo and then push to it.

Comment: @duenni That is a solution, but the goal is to leave out any user interaction besides pushing lot it as origin as if it was already set up using `git init —bare`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being based on #2:

> Changing git functionality on the server side, hijacking push commands (called in the git-shell?). I have found no documentation on what takes place on the server side when pushing over SSH so I've not been able to further investigate this possible solution.

I found an [article by "kamalmarhubi"](http://kamalmarhubi.com/blog/2015/11/21/using-strace-to-figure-out-how-git-push-over-ssh-works/) that explained what `git push` was doing when set up to use SSH.

### The solution

#### Set up - server side

Add a used called `git`:

```
sudo useradd -m git
```

Note that the user unfortunately cannot use the git-shell since the shell handles necessary commands internally.

Create the `.ssh` directory

```
mkdir .ssh
```

Create the `authorized_keys` file

```
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Add any public keys you're going to use as a line to the `authorized_keys` file.

Add the following **on top of** the user's `.bashrc` file:

```
function git-receive-pack() {
  if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
    mkdir -p $1 && cd $1 && git init --quiet --bare && command git-receive-pack $@
  fi
}
```

#### Setup - client side

Execute the following within any git repository:

```
git add remote origin git@server:directory
```

Where `server` is the ip or name of the server and `directory` the path to store the repository at (relative to the git user's home directory, usually `/home/git/`).

### Usage

#### Pushing code from the client

Push as usually, the service has taken care of initializing the repository for you!

### How it works

Whenever Git pushes over SSH, it calls `ssh git@server git-receive-pack directory`, i.e. runs `git-receive-pack directory` on the remote. When using the git-shell, the command is handled internally. When using a regular shell (bash) the command is handled as any other bash command. This means that we can override how the command works, which we do by defining our own `git-receive-pack` in `.bashrc`. The definition needs to be on the top of the file since `.bashrc` usually aborts execution if it is run in a non-interactive shell (like Git is). The command we define checks to see if the target repository already exists, if it doesn't, it initializes it as a bare repository (as per Git standard) before it runs the original `git-receive-pack` which takes care of the actual pushing.